# Counting maximum sum of node value and counting the specific path which gives the sum [C]

Tags: c, count, tree, structure

Ok guys, I have an interesting question here. The task I was given says I should calculate the maximum sum of the given tree from root to the leaf. In this case that is 14. Well, the problem is that I also need to count the length of that exact path and somewhat return it also because I need to divide the sum with that path length. It sure as hell sounds complicated, at first I thought it was very easy but then I couldnt find a way to count the nodes through a specific path. Maybe the entire function `count()` was wrongly assembled because it leaves no space for the specific task I need to get done. If there are more questions please feel free to write em down, I need this answered. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tree{
    int i;
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
};
int count(struct tree *root);
int max(int,int);
int main()
{
    struct tree *p=NULL, *q=NULL, *r=NULL, *t=NULL;

    //1
    p=(struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    if(p==NULL) exit(1);
    p->i=1;
    p->left=NULL;
    p->right=NULL;

    //2
    q=(struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    if(q==NULL) exit(1);
    q->i=2;
    q->left=NULL;
    q->right=NULL;
    p->left=q;

    //3
    r=(struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    if(r==NULL) exit(1);
    r->i=3;
    r->left=NULL;
    r->right=NULL;
    p->right=r;

    t=q;

    //4
    q=(struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    if(q==NULL) exit(1);
    q->i=4;
    q->left=NULL;
    q->right=NULL;
    t->left=q;

    //5
    q=(struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    if(q==NULL) exit(1);
    q->i=5;
    q->left=NULL;
    q->right=NULL;
    t->right=q;

    t=q;

    //6
    q=(struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    if(q==NULL) exit(1);
    q->i=6;
    q->left=NULL;
    q->right=NULL;
    t->left=q;

    //7
    q=(struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    if(q==NULL) exit(1);
    q->i=7;
    q->left=NULL;
    q->right=NULL;
    r->right=q;
    printf("The sum is %d!",count(p));
}
int count(struct tree *root){
    if(root->left!=NULL && root->right!=NULL){
        return root->i+max(count(root->left),count(root->right));
    }
    else if(root->left==NULL && root->right!=NULL){
        return root->i+count(root->right);
    }
    else if(root->left!=NULL && root->right==NULL){
        return root->i+count(root->left);
    }
    else{
        return root->i;
    }
}
int max(int a, int b){
    if(a>b){
        return a;
    }
    else{
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: "It sure as hell sounds complicated" - Neither does it sound like that, nor is it. However, we are no "do my homework" site. See [ask]. What is your **specific** problem? What have you tried?

Comment: I tried everything but it wont work and I understand why it doesnt - I cant find a solution. The problem is simple - this function gives me the highest sum from root to leaf but I cant figure out how to count those specific nodes.

Comment: Why not passing an additional parameter `int *pathlen` to `count()` that holds the length of this (sub-)path? When you step down the branches and reach a leave you set it to 1. While you climb back upwards you take the len from sub-path and increment by 1.

Comment: That sounds like a thing I did but it gave me the length of the tree?

Comment: @SlavkoKovačević What do you mean with "Length of the tree"? Total number of nodes or longest path? If you take the correct pathlen for the same subtree as you take for the largest sum, you should get the correct length. You should give it a try.

Comment: Can you edit the code so I can understand your idea? I really cant get it. Would be much appreciated!

Comment: `struct path { int len, sum; struct path *next; /* struct tree *node; */ }; struct path searchPathOfMaxSum(struct tree *root);`

Comment: What exactly is this? And how does this solve my problem BLUEPIXY?

Comment: The path can be obtained by integrating the path from the leaf. /*Also return pointer */

Comment: I just need its length, not the entire path... I just need to know how long it is.

Comment: Use `struct lenAndSum { int len, sum; };` instead of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to change everything but only adjust your code...

```
typedef struct {
  int len;
  int sum;
} path_t;

path_t count(struct tree *root) {
    path_t a = { .len = 0, .sum = 0};
    path_t b = { .len = 0, .sum = 0};
    path_t ret;

    if (root == NULL)
      return a;  // empty sub-tree

    a = count(root->left);
    b = count(root->right);

    if (a.sum > b.sum) {
      ret.sum = a.sum:
      ret.len = a.len;
    } else {
      ret.sum = b.sum:
      ret.len = b.len;
    }
    ret.sum += root->i;
    ret.len ++;
    return ret;
}
```

Some details you might need to take care:
Initializing .sum to 0 might not be sufficient if the tree can hold negative numbers.
For `a.sum == b.sum` I simply take `b`. You might want to decide based on length of path or always chose `a` instead of `b`.